TS/JS | How to use uppy for images and video uploads to cloudflare
I am trying to implement images and video uploads to Cloudflare stream services and image services using Uppy/Tus. I have been wandering around the documentation of Uppy cannot figure the part where, using multiple uploader plugins in single instance of Uppy.
CF -> cloudflare

I am using CF stream's + CF images as for my media contents, and using Uppy dashboard.
And I want to use Tus in specific conditions, and also use Xhr on specific conditions only.
So, like using two plugins in same instance is not going well as expected.
Because when a upload is triggered both the endpoints will be triggered.
//core-tsx
 const [ref] = useState(
    new Uppy({
      id: "xx-global-uploader---",
      debug: false,
    })
      .use(XHRUpload, {
        endpoint: endpoints.uploader("/uploads/v1/sign/image"),
        formData: true,
        fieldName: "file",
      })
      .use(Tus, {
        endpoint: "/uploads/v1/sign/video",
        addRequestId: true,
      })
  );
  useUppyEvent(ref, "files-added", (files) =>
    handleFilesAddedEvents(files, ref, props, (message) => {
      toast.error(message);
    })
  );

There are multiple Plugins being used, and how do I stop one being used for specific files?
Let's say
image || Video < 50MB -> Xhr
video > 50MB -> Tus

I have tried This way of handling things but, it works, and uploads the Images and videos to specified endpoints, but throws an error because one failed.
export function handleFilesAddedEvents(
  files: UppyFile<Meta, Record<string, never>>[],
  uppy: Uppy<Meta, Record<string, never>>,
  meta: TMetadatas,
  errorCb: (message: string) => void
) {
  files.map((item) => {
    let isVideo = allowedVideoTypes.includes(item.type);
    let isImage = allowedImageTypes.includes(item.type);
    let isUploadable = isVideo || isImage;

    if (!isUploadable) {
      errorCb(`${item.extension} is not supported.`);
      uppy.removeFile(item.id);
    }

    if (isVideo) {
      uppy.setFileState(item.id, {
        xhrUpload: undefined,
        tus: {
          endpoint: endpoints.uploader(
            `/uploads/v1/sign/video?relId=${meta.relationId}&visibility=${meta.visibility}`
          ),
          chunkSize: 150 * 1024 * 1024,
          retryDelays: [0, 3000, 5000, 10000, 20000],
          onBeforeRequest: (req) => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
              let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = req.getUnderlyingObject();
              if (req.getURL().includes(import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL)) {
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
                let token = sessionStorage.getItem("authToken");
                if (token) {
                  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
                }
              } else {
                xhr.withCredentials = false;
              }
              resolve(() => {});
            });
          },
        },
      });
      return;
    }
    uppy.setFileState(item.id, {
      xhrUpload: {
        endpoint: endpoints.uploader("/uploads/v1/sign/image"),
        formData: true,
        method: "POST",
        fieldName: "file",
        onBeforeRequest(xhr) {
          if (files[0] && allowedVideoTypes.includes(files[0].type)) {
            console.log("I have been called?");
            xhr.abort();
            return;
          }
          let token = sessionStorage.getItem("authToken");
          if (token) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
          }
        },
      },
    });
  });
}

